# PHP Unable to load dynamic library (Image not found)

Tags: php, apache, debugging, dll, xampp

I use MacOSX and use XAMPP server. When I run composer on terminal it worked correctly but it always show php warning messages. How can I solve this? Please help.

Here are the error messages:

```
Macintosh:~ SarapMax$ composer
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_bz2.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_bz2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_bz2.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_bz2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_curl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_curl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_curl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_curl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_exif.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_exif.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_exif.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_exif.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_fileinfo.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_fileinfo.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_fileinfo.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_fileinfo.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_gd2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_gd2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mbstring.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mbstring.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mbstring.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mbstring.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Looks like you have installed the Windows version of XAMPP !!!!

Comment: how to solve this, help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually looks like you've uncommented the windows extensions lines in XAMP's php.ini file.  If not, then I'd take Alexsandro's suggestion of reinstalling.

If you did uncomment those lines -

Edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini and add the semicolon's  back in under Windows Extensions that will fix your initial problem with the error message.

You can use the GUI to restart the webserver and it will pick up the changes.

Then go to http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php and check to make sure all the extensions you need are getting loaded automatically.

-Jon

Comment: Oh! thank a lot, I've uncommented the windows extensions lines in XAMP's php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall the XAMP. Don't make sense your composer is trying to load DLLs once it is a Windows lib extension.

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead